# Как остановить следующую анимацию при клике если не закончилась старая?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как остановить следующую анимацию при клике если не закончилась старая? Проблема в том, что при нажатии несколько раз на ссылку начинает зависать плавная анимация и прокрутить страницу становится невозможно, она начинает трястись.

```js
$('.js-choice-item').click(function () {
 $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('.js-choice-item').removeClass('active');
 $('.option-load-st').hide();
 $('#method-' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
 let height = $('.choice-load__content').offset().top;
 $('body,html').animate({
  'scrollTop': height,
 }, 1200);
 return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice-load__content choice-load__an-content">
      <div id="method-leader-an" class="option-load-an option-load option-leader">
       <div class="option-image">
        <div class="option-image__leader option-image__picture"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="option-content">
        <h4 class="option-content__text">Данный способ получения позволяет получить деньги моментально. Дополнительная комиссия за перевод данным способом
         составляет 2.8 %. Бесплатный способ получения –</h4>
        <a href="#methodBank" class="option-text__link">Банковский счет</a>
        <p class="option-content__list-text">Чтобы получить заём по системе Лидер необходимо:</p>
        <ol class="option-list option-content__text">
         <li class="option-list__item option-content__list-text option-content__point">Узнать, где находится ближайший к Вашему дому офис системы Лидер.
          <a href="#methodBank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-leader-issue"
           class="option-text__link option-text__small">Найти ближайший офис системы Лидер</a>
         </li>
         <li class="option-list__item option-content__list-text option-content__point">Отправиться в офис и получить необходимую сумму, предоставив паспорт и указав номер перевода, полученный по SMS.</li>
        </ol>
        <a id="leader-confirm" href="/_hn:action%7Cr28_r1_r1%7C/cabinet/getmethod?method=selectLeader" class="form-footer__button getmethod-approved__button">Выбрать этот способ</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="method-contact-an" class="option-load-an option-load option-creditomat option-active">
       <div class="option-image">
        <div class="option-image__creditomat option-image__picture"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="option-content">
        <h4 class="option-content__text">Данный способ получения позволяет получить деньги моментально. Дополнительная комиссия за перевод данным способом
         составляет 3.0 %. Бесплатный способ получения –</h4>
        <a href="#methodBank" class="option-text__link">Банковский счет</a>
        <p class="option-content__list-text">Чтобы получить заём через систему CONTACT, необходимо:</p>
        <ol class="option-list option-content__text">
         <li class="option-list__item option-content__list-text option-content__point">Узнать, где находится ближайший к Вашему дому офис системы CONTACT.
          <a href="#methodBank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-leader-issue"
           class="option-text__link option-text__small">Найти ближайший офис системы Contact</a>
         </li>
         <li class="option-list__item option-content__list-text option-content__point">Отправиться в офис и получить необходимую сумму, предоставив паспорт и указав номер перевода, полученный по SMS.</li>
        </ol>
        <p class="option-content__text">Код нашей организации в системе CONTACT: GEFV</p>
        <a class="option-content__important-text">Этот способ выбран</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="method-bank-an" class="option-load-an option-load option-bank">
       <div class="option-image">
        <div class="option-image__bank option-image__picture"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="option-content">
        <h4 class="option-content__text"> Дополнительная комиссия за перевод средств данным способом не взимается</h4>
        <p class="option-content__text">Чтобы получить заём на банковский счет, укажите реквизиты счета, открытого на Ваше имя.</p>
        <div class="form-container clearfix">
         <form method="post" action="/_hn:action%7Cr80_r3%7C/discount-terms" class="form-container__list">
          <fieldset class="form-item">
           <label for="item__bank-name" class="form-item__name">Название банка</label>
           <input id="item__bank-name" name="item__bank-name" type="text" placeholder="Банк" required="required"
            class="form-item__input" />
           <i title="Это поле является обязательным" class="form-item__icon"></i>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="form-item">
           <label for="bik" class="form-item__name">БИК
            <a href="/scheme#faq-bik" class="label__link">Как узнать свой БИК?</a>
           </label>
           <input id="bik" name="bik" type="text" placeholder="000000000" required="required" class="form-item__input"
           />
           <i title="Это поле является обязательным" class="form-item__icon"></i>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="form-item">
           <label for="item__number" class="form-item__name">Номер счета</label>
           <input id="item__number" name="item__number" type="text" placeholder="000-00-000-0-0000-0000000"
            required="required" class="form-item__input" />
           <i title="Это поле является обязательным" class="form-item__icon"></i>
          </fieldset>
         </form>
        </div>
        <p class="option-content__text">* Время перевода денег зависит от банка, услугами которого Вы пользуетесь.</p>
        <a id="bank-request" class="form-footer__button getmethod-approved__button">Сохранить реквизиты</a>
        <a id="bank-confirm" href="/_hn:action%7Cr28_r1_r1%7C/cabinet/getmethod?method=selectBank"
         class="form-footer__button getmethod-approved__button">Выбрать этот способ</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="method-qiwi-an" class="option-load-an option-load option-electronic">
       <div class="option-image">
        <div class="option-image__electronic option-image__picture"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="option-content">
        <h4 class="option-content__text">Данный способ получения позволяет получить деньги моментально. Дополнительная комиссия за перевод данным способом
         составляет 2.5 %. Бесплатный способ получения –
         <a href="#methodBank" class="option-text__link">Банковский счет</a>
        </h4>
        <p class="option-content__text">Воспользовавшись услугами Visa QIWI Wallet, Вы можете быстро получить деньги, не выходя из дома. Дополнительная
         регистрация в сервисе QIWI не требуется.</p>
        <p class="option-content__text">Мы переведем денежные средства на Ваш QIWI-кошелек, который автоматически создается при регистрации по номеру телефона.</p>
        <p
         class="option-content__text">Необходимая сумма моментально окажется на Вашем счете в Visa QIWI Wallet. Для того, чтобы обналичить сумму, войдите
         в личный кабинет QIWI и воспользуйтесь функцией «Вывод средств».</p>
         <p class="option-content__text">Подробнее смотрите на сайте
          <a href="http://qiwi.ru/" target="_blank" class="option-text__link">qiwi.ru</a>
         </p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="method-yamoney-an" class="option-load-an option-load option-yandex">
       <div class="option-image">
        <div class="option-image__yandex option-image__picture"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="option-content">
        <p class="option-content__text">Воспользовавшись услугами Яндекс.Денег, Вы можете быстро получить заем на Ваш кошелек, не выходя из дома. Регистрация
         электронного кошелька займет у Вас не более трех минут.</p>
        <p class="option-content__text">Мы моментально переведем денежные средства на Ваш кошелек Яндекс.Деньги, привязанный к личному кабинету на сайте
         <a
          href="https://www.smsfinance.ru/" data-toggle="tab" class="option-text__link">smsfinance.ru</a>
        </p>
        <p class="option-content__text">Вы можете оплатить тысячи товаров и услуг, вывести денежные средства на карту или получить наличными.</p>
        <p class="option-content__text">Дополнительная комиссия за перевод данным способом составляет 3.5 %. Бесплатный способ получения –</p>
        <a href="#methodBank"
         data-toggle="tab" class="option-text__link">Банковский счет</a>
        <p class="option-content__text">Подробнее смотрите на сайте
         <a href="https://money.yandex.ru/" target="_blank" class="option-text__link">money.yandex.ru</a>
        </p>
        <p class="option-content__text">Введите номер своего кошелька в системе Яндекс.Деньги. Если у Вас нет кошелька, Вы можете зарегистрировать его
         на сайте
         <a href="https://money.yandex.ru/" target="_blank" class="option-text__link">money.yandex.ru</a>. Кошелек должен быть минимум 11 символов длиной, Вы не можете зарегистрировать кошелек с меньшим
         числом знаков.</p>
        <div class="form-container clearfix">
         <form method="post" action="/_hn:action%7Cr28_r1_r1%7C/cabinet/getmethod?method=yandexRequest" class="form-container__list">
          <fieldset class="form-item">
           <label for="item__number" class="form-item__name">Номер кошелька Яндекс.Деньги</label>
           <input name="item__number" type="text" placeholder="41001" required="required"
            class="form-item__input" />
           <i title="Это поле является обязательным" class="form-item__icon"></i>
          </fieldset>
         </form>
        </div>
        <a id="yandex-request" class="form-footer__button getmethod-approved__button">Сохранить номер кошелька</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="method-card-an" class="option-load-an option-load option-card">
       <div class="option-image">
        <div class="option-image__card option-image__picture"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="option-content">
        <h4 class="option-content__text">Данный способ получения позволяет получить деньги моментально. Дополнительная комиссия за перевод данным способом
         составляет 3.5 %. Бесплатный способ получения –</h4>
        <a href="#methodBank" data-toggle="tab" class="option-text__link">Банковский счет
         <br> Перевод средств на карты Сбербанка может занимать до трех рабочих дней.</a>
        <p class="option-content__list-text">Для получения займа на банковскую карту необходимо пройти процедуру регистрации.</p>
        <ol class="option-list option-content__text">
         <li class="option-list__item option-content__list-text option-content__point">Нажмите на кнопку «Регистрация» и введите данные Вашей карты, после чего на Вашем счете будет временно заблокирована
          сумма не более пяти рублей</li>
         <li class="option-list__item option-content__list-text option-content__point">Для завершения регистрации введите точное значение этой суммы.</li>
        </ol>
        <p class="option-content__text">Обращаем внимание владельцев карт Сбербанка: регистрация может быть произведена, только если у Вас подключена услуга
         «Мобильный банк»</p>
        <p class="option-content__text option-content__important-text">Денежные средства могут быть перечислены на банковскую карту Visa или MasterCard</p>
        <div class="form-container">
         <form action="/_hn:action%7Cr33_r1_r1_r1%7C/cabinet/return" class="form-container__list">
          <fieldset class="form-item">
           <input name="method" type="hidden" value="start-verify-card" />
           <button class="form-footer__button getmethod-approved__small-button">Регистрация</button>
          </fieldset>
         </form>
        </div>
        <a class="form-footer__pay-button form-footer__button concealer-button">Выбрать этот способ</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите код. У Вас только JS, без верстки.

Comment: Добавил код....

Comment: Я бы поставил флаг isAnimate и запретил бы щелкать на ссылку/элемент анимации много раз. Меньше проблем тогда возникает. Т.е. код типа `if (isAnimate) return; ...... $('body,html').animate({'scrollTop': height,}, 1200); isAnimate = true;`

Comment: Не понял данное решение

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('body,html').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': height,
}, 1200);
```

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: должно, вообще почему вы анимируете body, html ? кажется вообще надо `window` анимировать.